# kafka-connect: flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Please help me with this error

`connect-distributed[889911]: [2021-06-23 12:06:27,945] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=jdbc_source_oracle-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:482)`

Config connect source:

```
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
"tasks.max": "1",
"connection.attempts": "1",
"connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521:SID",
"connection.user": "*****",
"connection.password": "******",
"topic.prefix": "ddb-",
"mode": "bulk",
"query": "SELECT ISU_CD, ISU_NM, UPD_DT FROM TBCB_BND",
"poll.interval.ms": 60000
```

Increased the parameter  "**offset.flush.timeout.ms**", but to no avail

Comment: That is an INFO message saying no work needs to be done, not an error... What is the exact _problem_ you are running into?

Comment: The topic is empty, the data does not come. If I specify "table.whitelist" table, the data comes, but I only need identified fields

Comment: What "identified tables"? The whitelist property is required if you want to read something. You need to remove `FROM [table]` in the query, and move `TBCB_BND` to be `table.whitelist`